# Reading entire file into stringstream

Tags: c++

So, I would like to parse a file through some kind of stream and I could indeed just simply use the ifstream class, but the problem is that I'm aiming for performance and all those >> operators for the ifstream class could really slow down my program.
So I came up with the idea to somehow read the entire file into a std::stringstream, and then parse the file with the stringstream.
I would like to do something like this, but I could not get it to work:

```
std::ifstream fin( p_Filename.c_str( ) );
fin.seekg( 0, std::ifstream::end );
int fileSize = static_cast<int>( fin.tellg( ) );
fin.seekg( 0, std::ifstream::beg );

std::stringstream       ss;
ss.str( ).resize( fileSize );
fin.read( const_cast<char*>( ss.str( ).c_str( ) ), fileSize );
```

Comment: All you really need is `ss << fin.rdbuf();`.

Comment: `but the problem is that I'm aiming for performance and all those >> operators for the ifstream class could really slow down my program` And you know this because you've written your app and profiled accordingly, right?

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the size of the file, like you have done.
2. Allocate an array of `char` to hold the contents.
3. Read the entire file into the `char` array using `istream::read`.
4. Create a `istringstream` that uses the `char` array. Use it to parse the data.
5. Deallocate the array of `char`.

**Update**

Make sure you open the file in binary mode if you want to follow this strategy. Thanks @ooga.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: How am I assigning the char array to the istringstream without making a copy of the content?

Comment: @grimgrom, Why do you need `std::istringstream`?

Comment: @ooga:  "binary mode" only applies to Windows.  Most programs don't need to be concerned with it.

Comment: @wallyk I'm well-aware of that (although it certainly does not "only apply to Windows"). But portability is important to most people.

Comment: @Thomas Because I'm going to parse the file from a stringstream.

Comment: @ooga:  Oh, yes.  It also applies to Vax/VMS.  (Do you know of any others?)  Fortunately, all the "always binary" o/s runtime libraries accept and ignore an explicit binary mode qualifier, so it does indeed make it more portable to specify.

Comment: Instead of using a `char` buffer, you could read the file into a `std::string`, eliminating the need for a `stringstream`.

Comment: @grimgrom `std::istringstream` can be constructed using a `std::string`. The `std::sting` can be constructed from the `char` array. `std::string` will make a copy of the `char` array.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but strings doesn't have the >> operator, which makes parsing so much easier.

Comment: @R Sahu "std::istringstream can be constructed using a std::string". By "Constrcuted, do you mean copied or just pointing to the string?

Comment: @grimgrom `std::istringstream` makes a copy of the input `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is invalid.

If the `>>` operators are going to be an overhead, they will have the same overhead operating on a string, and by reading the entire file before processing any of it you are just adding latency, i.e. wasting time and space.

You don't need to do this. Just ensure there is adequate buffering on the `fstream.`